# Unity create scenes and add content to it in the editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I want to do:

1. I have a list of Sector gameObjects on my scene
2. I want to iterate through and create a new scene for it, scene_sector_xxx
3. the scene's content will be the gameObject only at that position
4. add this scene to runtime

Why I want this?

I need to create an async/additive scene loader at runtime to speed up everything. When the player is near by a sector then just want to load that sector piece immediatelly.

Is it possible? In editor maybe?

**Update:**
my code:

```
    private static IEnumerator SaveSectorToSceneCoroutine(Sector sector)
    {
        
        //TODO save this go to a new scene
        var go = Object.Instantiate(sector.gameObject);
        //Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(go); //this is not working from editor
        //or need a prefab?

      

        var newScene = EditorSceneManager.NewScene(NewSceneSetup.EmptyScene, NewSceneMode.Single); //maybe better from calling this in the background, how?
        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(go, newScene); //this not working, "go" became null

     

        string[] path = EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene().path.Split(char.Parse("/"));
        path[path.Length - 1] = "_SCN_SECTOR_" + go.name + path[path.Length - 1];
        EditorSceneManager.SaveScene(newScene, string.Join("/", path), true);
      
        Debug.Log("Saved Scene " + path);   
    }
```

Comment: Yes this is possible. Only in the editor as you can not create new scenes once your app is built. you **can** create scenes on runtime as well ... but what good would this be in your case? .... now what exactly is your question? ;)

Comment: You might also want to look into [Addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.addressables.html) .. there is no need to go for scenes explicitly ...I would e.g. have some trigger object and on trigger enter load and instantiate according addressable async and later on unload it again

Comment: @derHugo I updated my code, please check...

Comment: @derHugo I have a very big scene, with lot of Sector components on that. I want to create SCENES from all my SECTOR-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably in [`EditorSceneManager.NewScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.NewScene.html).

As mode you are passing in [`NewSceneMode.Single`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.NewSceneMode.Single.html)

> All current open Scenes are closed and the newly created Scene are opened.

What you rather want to use is [`NewSceneMode.Additive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.NewSceneMode.Additive.html)

> The newly created Scene is added to the current open Scenes.

like e.g.

```
var go = Object.Instantiate(sector.gameObject);

var newScene = EditorSceneManager.NewScene(NewSceneSetup.EmptyScene, NewSceneMode.Additive); 

SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(go, newScene); 

string[] path = EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene().path.Split('//'));
path[path.Length - 1] = "_SCN_SECTOR_" + go.name + path[path.Length - 1];
EditorSceneManager.SaveScene(newScene, string.Join('//', path), true);

EditorSceneManager.CloseScene(newScene, true);
  
Debug.Log("Saved Scene " + path);
```

---

Then I don't think this should be a Coroutine. I don't see any need for/use of doing

```
yield return null;
```

in this use case

Comment: I tried additive before. It is not what I need. But also Single is bad for me. I just want to create a new scene in the background and not show everywhere. Also copy some things to there and just save that scene

Comment: @lacas well .. it is exactly what you need then. Since you use `Single` the object you instantiate is unloaded ... you want additive, move it there, save, then unload the additive scene again

Comment: you are right. After it just unload that scene... and tadamm, working:)